# Ruby on Rails has many categories association scope issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am making an app in which there are three models individual, company and event. 
company,event and individual lies in a single category.
here the company can create an event where they can choose multiple interests from categories and search for individuals that lies in that categories also when individual signs up they can choose multiple interests from categories table to find the companies of the interests and this same applies for company.

the solution I want is to prepare the best logic for this

my assumption is to create an Interest model where company , event and individuals has_many interests and interest belongs_to category

but this assumption seems to be confusing

Please suggest some logics

Comment: Seems fine to me.  Does a company need to have interests?  They could just have them via their events.  I assume individuals would be searching for events matching their interests?

Comment: company can also search events matching their interests.

Comment: events are made and destroyed, the company has two types of search area , one via their event interests and other by their profile's interest , event interests vary event to event but profile interests are fixed

Comment: I don't think you're going to get it any better than what you've described.

Comment: thank you ill stick to it then